# load second view from the first view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I am currently develop iphone app.
the type of the app is Tab Bar. so i heave 4 tabs that in each tab i have different view.
(each view have controller for itself)

now in the first view i am loading data from the net and when it finished i want automaticly to jump to the second tab controller(to show the result).

but u cant find the way to load the second view from the first view?????????

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: thanks..

maybe you can tell me how i can refresh the celles in the table view?
lets say i made i logic change in the celles and when i move to other window and return to the previous window the cell stay at the old position.

Comment: Since that has nothing to do with the original question, you should post another question.

Comment: ok i tryied self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; 
but the window stay on the first view.
maybe i miss somthing?